# perl `require` for file given by variable

Tags: perl, require

I want to use a module that the path to the file will be in a variable.

I tried using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Getopt::Long;

my ($library, $zipped, $aid_class_file);
GetOptions ("aid_class_file=s"  =>  \$aid_class_file,
            "res_lib=s"         =>  \$library,
            "zip"               =>  \$zipped);

require $aid_class_file;
```

but it doesn't work. How do I do it?

**edit:**
The error message is:

```
Can't locate Error.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at /nfs/iil/disks/home10/imelam2/learn_flow/flow_to_change/AidClass.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /nfs/iil/disks/home10/imelam2/learn_flow/flow_to_change/AidClass.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at statistics.pl line 11.
```

I want to add the file called `AidClass.pm` and not `Error.pm`

I ran using the line:

```
statistics.pl -aid_class_file="/nfs/iil/disks/home10/imelam2/learn_flow/flow_to_change/AidClass.pm"
```

Comment: @Prix, you are right, thnx.write it as an Answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: @llya hope your problem got solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error demonstrates that the AidClass cannot find the Error.pm file which causes it to crash. The Error.pm is called at line 6 of the AidClass.pm:

`Can't locate Error.pm`

It is looking for it on the following path:

```
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
```

Depending on how your AidClass is you could add its directory as a lib in the AidClass.pm so it will look for the Error.pm in there as well:

```
use lib '/nfs/iil/disks/home10/imelam2/learn_flow/flow_to_change/';
use Error;
```

Or you could do that from the script you are calling AidClass and instead of calling `use Error;` call `use AidClass;` and if the Error.pm is within the folder it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say in what way it "doesn't work", so this is all a bit of a guess.

Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)? In particular the bit that talks about loading modules using a variable.

> If EXPR is a bareword, the require
>   assumes a ".pm" extension and replaces
>   "::" with "/" in the filename for you,
>   to make it easy to load standard
>   modules. This form of loading of
>   modules does not risk altering your
>   namespace.
>
> In other words, if you try this:
>
> ```
> require Foo::Bar; # a splendid bareword
> ```
>
> The require function will actually
>   look for the "Foo/Bar.pm" file in the
>   directories specified in the @INC
>   array.
>
> But if you try this:
>
> ```
> $class = 'Foo::Bar';
> require $class; # $class is not a bareword
> #or
> require "Foo::Bar"; # not a bareword because of the ""
> ```
>
> The require function will look for the
>   "Foo::Bar" file in the @INC array and
>   will complain about not finding
>   "Foo::Bar" there. In this case you can
>   do:
>
> ```
> eval "require $class";
> ```

Comment: Actually for a similar problem I had, it worked *without* using `eval`: I used something like `$req_name = $mod_name . '.pm'; $req_name =~ s,::,/,g; require $req_name;` (`$mode_name` is the usual module name like `XML::Twig::XPath`)