# XML::Twig::XPath: `findnodes` still compains I should use `findnodes` instead of `get_xpath`

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-twig

I wrote some Perl module that builds an XML::Twig tree.
Unfortunately it seems that `XML::Twig`'s XPath implementation is incomplete, so I loaded `XML::Twig::XPath`.

As the documentation for XML::Twig states that `findnodes` is the same as `get_xpath` (among several more), I was expecting that I could process a query like `//info_string[text()]` that the original `XML::Twig` did not like.

On the first run `XML::Twig::XPath` complained that I'll have to use `getnodes` instead of `get_xpath`, so I changed that.

Unfortunately even after that change, I still get the same message:

```text
error in xpath expression //info_string[text()] at text()
the expression is a valid XPath statement, and you are using XML::Twig::XPath, but
you are using either 'find_nodes' or 'get_xpath' where the method you likely wanted
to use is 'findnodes', which is the only one that uses the full XPath engine
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.18.2/XML/Twig.pm line 3566.
```

I'm confused.

The statement in question looks like this:

```perl
return $self->_XML()->findnodes($XPath);
```

The `_XML()` method returns the `XML::Twig` tree, and `findnodes` is expected to query that tree.

I had also tried to replace `use XML::Twig` with `use XML::Twig::XPath`, but that didn't change the message, too.

### Details

As the code to create the data structure and the XML from it is overly complex, I' just going to present the XML output (`$self->_XML()->print`) and the data structure (via `Data::Dumper`) here.

The XML to query looks like this:

```xml
<MonitoringOutput id="test-id" version="0.1">
  <description>This is a test output</description>
  <exit_code>0</exit_code>
  <status_string>OK</status_string>
  <info_string>(demo): Some interesting story</info_string>
  <perf_string>L1=0.49 L2=4.7s;;;0;7 L3=0.6;@0.2:0.3</perf_string>
  <perf_data count="3">
    <sample label="L3">
      <label>L3</label>
      <value>0.6</value>
      <thresholds>
        <warn end="0.3" inverted="1" start="0.2"/>
      </thresholds>
    </sample>
    <sample label="L1">
      <label>L1</label>
      <value>0.49</value>
    </sample>
    <sample label="L2">
      <label>L2</label>
      <value unit="s">4.7</value>
      <unit>s</unit>
      <range max="7" min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <warn_labels count="0"/>
    <crit_labels count="0"/>
  </perf_data>
</MonitoringOutput>
```

This is my attempt to make a reproducible minimal example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;
use XML::Twig::XPath;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parse('<MonitoringOutput id="test-id" version="0.1">
  <description>This is a test output</description>
  <exit_code>0</exit_code>
  <status_string>OK</status_string>
  <info_string>(demo): Some interesting story</info_string>
  <perf_string>L1=0.49 L2=4.7s;;;0;7 L3=0.6;@0.2:0.3</perf_string>
  <perf_data count="3">
    <sample label="L3">
      <label>L3</label>
      <value>0.6</value>
      <thresholds>
        <warn end="0.3" inverted="1" start="0.2"/>
      </thresholds>
    </sample>
    <sample label="L1">
      <label>L1</label>
      <value>0.49</value>
    </sample>
    <sample label="L2">
      <label>L2</label>
      <value unit="s">4.7</value>
      <unit>s</unit>
      <range max="7" min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <warn_labels count="0"/>
    <crit_labels count="0"/>
  </perf_data>
</MonitoringOutput>');
$twig->findnodes('//info_string[text()]');
```

When running it under the debugger (on a different machine with somewhat newer perl), I get this output:

```text
error in xpath expression //info_string[text()] at text()
the expression is a valid XPath statement, and you are using XML::Twig::XPath, but
you are using either 'find_nodes' or 'get_xpath' where the method you likely wanted
to use is 'findnodes', which is the only one that uses the full XPath engine
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/XML/Twig.pm line 3685.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/XML/Twig.pm line 7122.
    XML::Twig::Elt::_croak_and_doublecheck_xpath("//info_string[text()]", "error in xpath expression //info_string[text()] at text()") called at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/XML/Twig.pm line 7089
    XML::Twig::Elt::_install_xpath("//info_string[text()]") called at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/XML/Twig.pm line 7131
    XML::Twig::Elt::get_xpath(XML::Twig::Elt=HASH(0x5591017d3da0), "//info_string[text()]") called at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/XML/Twig.pm line 3685
    XML::Twig::get_xpath(XML::Twig=HASH(0x55910059bb00), "//info_string[text()]") called at /tmp/t.pl line 38
```

Comment: Please show us a sample of your XML.

Comment: @Dada Do you need the XML as text or as Perl structure? On the query: The pattern was taken from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: What we really need is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For instance, a small XML input, your code reading that input and creating an `XML::Twig` object, and then the query that doesn't work.

Comment: I've added the details as requested. Still I think the output of `ref $self->_XML()` would have been enough.

Comment: As mentioned by @Dada, it would be nice if you could construct a runnable example.. That would help clarify your question, and we could try to reproduce your observed behavior

Comment: It seems `Data::Dumper` was unable to present the `XML::Twig` as Perl instruction, so I used the alternative of re-parsing the output to build `XML::Twig` (as anybody else could have tried). See the revised question.

Comment: Actually I don't understand the two close votes. If that's a bad question, at leat 80% of all questions should be closed IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building the XML tree with full XPath support, it must be built using `XML::Twig::XPath->new` *and* elements added must be created using `XML::Twig::XPath::Elt->new` to make `findnodes` work.

As using XPath is kind of optional in my code, I decided to load either `XML::Twig` or `XML::Twig::XPath` dynamically, depending whether full XPath support is needed.
In addition my code has to use `XML::Twig::XPath::Elt` instead of `XML::Twig::Elt` for full XPath support.

So my code uses these tricks:

```perl
my $xml_twig = $use_xpath ? 'XML::Twig::XPath' : 'XML::Twig';
my $xml_twig_mod = $xml_twig . '.pm';
$xml_twig_mod =~ s,::,/,g;
require $xml_twig_mod;
my $xml = $xml_twig->new(...);
my $elt = "${xml_twig}::Elt"->new(...);
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5790563/6607497

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you need to use `XML::Twig::XPath` (and not `XML::Twig`) when you construct the twig object. The following works for me:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig::XPath->new();
$twig->parse( .... );
$twig->findnodes('//info_string[text()]');
```

Comment: I'll be away from my source code for some time (end of September), so I'll have to check at some later time. However the real XML tree is constructed differently, of course. Do you agree that the error message is confusing at least?

Comment: When replacing `XML::Twig` with `XML::Twig::XPath` in the constructor the original error message went away, but on further testing I got `Can't locate object method "node_cmp" via package "XML::Twig::Elt" ...`. My code is using a constructor `XML::Twig::Elt->new` to add elements, too. I tried to use `elt_class` using `$twig`, but failed (object method unknown).